# What is the correct way to use "forked" DIP sockets?

Tags: identification

In the dark depths of my parts bin I found a pair of connectors that appear to be some kind of DIP chip sockets, they look similar to these...

(Image source: [Farnell - Aries 14-600-10 14-way DIP Header](https://uk.farnell.com/aries/14-600-10/header-dil-14way/dp/1169107))

[image: Photo of DIP header]

To my mind they appear to be an alternative to "normal" press-fit IC sockets or turned-pin sockets.

How does one correctly use this kind of device?  Are the IC pins intended to be soldered to the forks?  Or is it friction fit?  Is this something else entirely?

Comment: I've used those many times for discrete parts like resistors, ceramic caps, BJTs, and so on. That's what they are intended for, I think. I have a bunch of them here. I can plug them into wire-wrap sockets, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a plug for building your own 'IC' that can plug into an IC socket. You can string leaded components like resistors, capacitors, diodes, transistors by dropping the lead into the fork and soldering. This is much less likely to accidentally short to the next pin than winding the wire round a pin.

They were very useful when every design started with a field of DIP sockets, but are almost unheard of now.

I once built a 4P4T 'switch' by using two of these plugged into two sockets, their orientations and positions changing the connectivity of the socket pins.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed!  Sounds like a prototyping tool - probably not for production use?

Comment: @user882326721 no reason not to use it in production, maybe epoxy over it to protect it, if the volume is small. That 4P4T switch I mentioned was on a 16 bit computer peripheral we delivered to a UK company, and days before delivery they wanted a 4 bit data path to be user rather than factory settable to any one of the 4 nybble slots of the 16 bit word.

Comment: You can get these with plastic caps that snap on the top to protect them.

Answer (score 2):

Can also be used to fit an SMD device to a breadboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They were also used as a configuration plug-in module to some kind of board.

Just imagine you have a board where a few function or gains or however settings are configured by some wire strap and/or resistors and/or capacitors values.

Having all of packed in a single socket would help service engineers in configuring anew board just like the one to be replaced.

The fork shape on top of pins just helps soldering configuration parts.

Answer (score 0):

These are mostly used for mounting leaded components onto a socketed (e.g., wire-wrap) prototype board. They’re ok for lower-frequency analog circuits like audio filters. The general layout models how through-hole boards are laid out: the passives for a block are grouped together alongside the IC. With good planning they work well.

For higher frequency work however the interconnect adds parasitic inductance and capacitance. You may be better off tacking the components directly onto the IC. This is especially true for bypassing.

They can also be used, in a pinch, to adapt SMT to DIP by using blue wires.